# How to click on one href which has certain words as text using selenium web driver java

Tags: java, selenium, text, href

I am trying to click on href which has neither id nor name. It has text as "Proof of Prior Insurance" . When i tried with xpath

```
"webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//form*[@name='plaRequiredDocumentsForm']/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a")).click()"
```

it prints "cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement " in console.

Website code is:

```
 <FORM method=post name=plaRequiredDocumentsForm>
    <INPUT name=expVIPCacheKey value=null type=hidden> 
    <INPUT name=wintag value=1411453320424 type=hidden> 
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=signatureOptionSection>
    <TABLE width=750>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD style="PADDING-LEFT: 10pt">
                Signature Option : <INPUT class=bodytext onclick="javascript: setPageDataChangeIndicator(); toggleSignatueStatus(this)" name=signature value=ePad type=radio value2="" value1="">
                    E-Pad &nbsp; <INPUT class=bodytext onclick="javascript: setPageDataChangeIndicator(); toggleSignatueStatus(this)" name=signature value=ink CHECKED type=radio value2="" value1=""> Ink 
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    </DIV>
    <TABLE width=750>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; PADDING-LEFT: 5pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 10pt">
                    <A onblur="if (this.children[0]) this.children[0].className='';window.defaultStatus=''" onfocus="if (this.children[0] != null) this.children[0].className='activeButton';window.defaultStatus='button exit    '" onmouseover="window.status='button exit    ';return true;" href="javascript:formExit()">
                    <IMG class=bodytext border=0 align=middle src="../../../images/button_exit.gif"></A>&nbsp; <A onblur="if (this.children[0]) this.children[0].className='';window.defaultStatus=''" onfocus="if (this.children[0] != null) this.children[0].className='activeButton';window.defaultStatus='button image center    '" onmouseover="window.status='button image center    ';return true;" href="javascript:imageCenterSubmit()"><IMG class=bodytext border=0 align=middle src="../../../images/image_center.gif"></A>&nbsp; 
                    <A onblur="if (this.children[0]) this.children[0].className='';window.defaultStatus=''" onfocus="if (this.children[0] != null) this.children[0].className='activeButton';window.defaultStatus='button refresh    '" onmouseover="window.status='button refresh    ';return true;" href="javascript:refresh()">
                    <IMG class=bodytext border=0 align=middle src="../../../images/button_refresh.gif"></A>&nbsp; 
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE><BR>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD style="PADDING-LEFT: 10pt"><FONT color=red size=2>
                    <B>IMPORTANT:</B> Scanning into the Application of Insurance document type will automatically apply a copy to the Subscription Agreement document type if a Subscription Agreement is required. Each document will be approved independently. </FONT>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE class=surroundingTable border=1 width=750>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD colSpan=2>
                    <TABLE class=txnTable>
                        <TBODY>
                            <TR class=sectionHeader>
                                <TD>
                                    <DIV style="FLOAT: left">Household Documents </DIV>
                                    <DIV style="FLOAT: right"><A tabIndex=-1 href="javascript:openHelpTagWindow('/TR/eAgent/Ade/eauto.help.ade?req_page=help&amp;TransType=NN&amp;StateCode=OH&amp;HelpTextId=H02710001')">
                                        <IMG border=0 src="../../../images/icon_question_mark_green_cropped.gif" width=15 height=15></A> 
                                    </DIV>
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TBODY>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD colSpan=2>
                    <TABLE class=surroundingTable>
                        <TBODY>
                            <TR>
                                <TD>
                                    <TABLE class=txnTable>
                                        <TBODY>
                                            <TR class=columnHeader>
                                                <TD>Household Number</TD>
                                                <TD>Document</TD>
                                                <TD>Status</TD>
                                                <TD>Customer Notified</TD>
                                                <TD>Due Date</TD>
                                                <TD>Signature</TD>
                                                <TD></TD>
                                            </TR>
                                        </TBODY>
                                    </TABLE>
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TBODY>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR><BR>
            <TR>
                <TD colSpan=2>
                    <TABLE class=txnTable>
                        <TBODY>
                            <TR class=sectionHeader>
                                <TD>
                                    <DIV style="FLOAT: left">Client Documents </DIV>
                                    <DIV style="FLOAT: right">
                                        <A tabIndex=-1 href="javascript:openHelpTagWindow('/TR/help.ade?req_page=help&amp;TransType=NN&amp;StateCode=OH&amp;HelpTextId=H02710002')">
                                        <IMG border=0 src="../../../images/icon_question_mark_green_cropped.gif" width=15 height=15></A> 
                                    </DIV>
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TBODY>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD colSpan=2>
                    <TABLE class=surroundingTable>
                        <TBODY>
                            <TR>
                                <TD>
                                    <TABLE class=txnTable>
                                        <TBODY>
                                            <TR class=columnHeader>
                                                <TD>Client Name</TD>
                                                <TD>Date of Birth</TD>
                                                <TD>Document</TD>
                                                <TD>Status</TD>
                                                <TD>Customer Notified</TD>
                                                <TD>Due Date</TD>
                                                <TD>Signature</TD>
                                                <TD></TD>
                                            </TR>
                                                <TR class=resultsOff>
                                                    <TD>KARTHICK KAMAL </TD>
                                                    <TD>December 24, 1986</TD>
                                                    <TD>
                                                        <A href="JavaScript:openDocumentWindow('null','A ','A0002','NR','CL',' 734383047','2566332','null','1611745392','734383047','false');">Affinity Discount Documentation </A>
                                                    </TD>
                                                    <TD>Not Received </TD>
                                                    <TD></TD>
                                                    <TD></TD>
                                                    <TD></TD>
                                                    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                                                </TR>
                                                <TR class=resultsOff>
                                                    <TD></TD>
                                                    <TD></TD>
                                                    <TD>
                                                        **<A href="JavaScript:openDocumentWindow('null','A ','A0054','NR','CL',' 734383047','2566332','null','1611745392','734383047','false');">Proof of Prior Insurance </A>**
                                                    </TD>
                                                </TR>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

use 'driver.findElements(By.cssLocator("td > a"))' method to get the list of elements.

Iterate each element in the said list and get the text in it and compare it to your expected text. Where it matches that is your element and then you can take an action on it.

Comment: Thanks varun, But my problem is not solved. I am using  List<WebElement> linkList=webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td > a"));".  It returns lot of href's exept what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath:

//a[contains(text(),'Proof of Prior Insurance')]